# Storage Manager on Synology DiskStation is blank and refuses to quit

Tags: linux, synology

On my Synology DiskStation DS1812+ (running DSM 5.0-4493 Update 3), the application Storage Manager is completely blank and refuses to quit. The application stays open even after restarting. How can I quit it and how can I restore it to a functioning state?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a cold reboot?  This means shutting the device down, turning it off, then turning it back on.  But the lack of information could be for a varity of reasons, do you have the current release installed

Comment: do you have the cloud/remote-access services enabled and running? there is currently a set of attacks on-going against web-accessible synology NAS products. http://www.macuser.co.uk/9285-synology-statement-synolocker-attack-nas-cryptolocker

Comment: @Ramhound I haven't tried cold rebooting, but I will later today when I get home. And yeah, this is the current version of DSM.

Comment: @FrankThomas I have Cloud Station installed, running, but not configured. I'll go ahead and remove it. I also use QuickConnect for remote access. However, Synology is saying that DSM 5.0 versions should be alright from CryptoLocker.

Comment: if you ssh into the nas (the username is root, not admin) are you disks mounted? can you see them with `mount`? if not how about`fdisk -l`? anything pertinent in `dmesg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this issue seems to have fixed itself. All of the sudden everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue now for about a week. I wrote to the support but got no answer since 3 days.

However I could solve the problem by chance.
I wanted to make a bookmark for my Quickconnect ID while being logged in throug my IP. So I ended up with two DS desktops in two different tabs. I hit the login button and the empty storage manager window was gone. So I closed the other tab with the opened empty storage manager and logged out on the other tab. Ironically the problem was solved. I opened up the storage manager and to my relief it displayed the healthy status of my volume.

I hope this helps other users with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where the StorageManager was blank and I have resolved it.
I will say how I resolved to help someone else:

- I logged into my NAS using `ssh`.
- I did a `top` command and saw that there were many `resize2fs` processes running.
  My CPU was maxed out near 100%.
- I killed all the `resize2fs` processes.
- I then logged back into my NAS through the web interface and the volumes were visible again in the StorageManager.

I hope this helps.